# Read a Char line to array until next line JAVA

Tags: java, char, arrays

I have a text file TEST.text with:

```
A B A A A A A A A A 
C D A C D C A D C A
```

There's always 10 chars in a line with many lines.

So what I want to do is to read each line into a char array, I'm really confused, so really need help

```
while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){ 

    text = inputFile.nextLine();                
char [] Arr = text.toCharArray();
```

I was trying to use toCharArray but that doesn't work for me. Please help.

Regards,

Comment: "that doesnt work" is not enough. What result you got and what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you expect all characters to be contained within the array, you could simply remove all the spaces

```
char[] array = text.replace(" ", "").toCharArray();
```

Comment: i guess it should be replaceall

Comment: @Reimeus, @upog: regex engine will be used in both `replace(String, String)` and `replaceAll(String, String)` methods. Only difference between them is that in `replace` regex metacharacters will be escaped with `Pattern.LITERAL` flag.

Comment: @Reimeus Yes, both methods will do the trick (especially since we are not using here regex metacharacters).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
char [] Arr = text.replaceAll(" ","").toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

`char [] Arr = text.toCharArray();` will read the space between char.

Try:

```
char[] Arr = text.replace(" ","").toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            BufferedReader br = null;

            try {

                String sCurrentLine;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    char [] Arr = sCurrentLine.replace(" ","").toCharArray()
// Performs your operation here 
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```